# mean value theorem question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I was trying to solve the following:

Given: $0 < a < b$ and $n>1$,
prove:
$$na^{n-1}(b-a) < b^n-a^n < nb^{n-1}(b-a)$$

I managed to get this far using the mean value theorem:
$$a^n(b-a)<b^n -a^n<b^n (b-a)$$
Any idea how to continue?

Comment: Please add the details on how obtained the second set of inequalites, because right now they are wrong.

Comment: Apply the Mean Value Theorem to  $f(x)=x^n-a^n$ on $[a,b]$. It looks like you tried this, but note $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)= x^n-a^n$ using the Mean Value Theorem
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{b^n - a^n}{b-a}$$ for some $c \in (a,b)$.
But $f'(c)= n \cdot c^{n-1}$ so 
$$\frac{b^n - a^n}{b-a} = n \cdot c^{n-1}$$

Now note that $n \cdot a^{n-1} < n \cdot c^{n-1} < n \cdot b^{n-1}$ so
$$ n \cdot a^{n-1} < \frac{b^n - a^n}{b-a} < n \cdot b^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without the use of the mean value theorem:

All terms are divisible by $(b-a)$. For the middle term, this is seen by the following formula
$$
(b^{n-1}+ab^{n-2}+a^2b^{n-3}+\ldots+a^{n-3}b^2+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-1})(b-a)=b^n-a^n
$$
Since $b-a>0$, we can factor it out, and the inequalities become
$$
na^{n-1}<b^{n-1}+ab^{n-2}+a^2b^{n-3}+\ldots+a^{n-3}b^2+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-1}<nb^{n-1}.
$$
But this becomes almost trivial by using $a<b$ repeatedly on all terms in the expression in the middle.

Comment: Very good answer +1. Just need to understand that this algebra works only if $n$ is a positive integer and perhaps could be extended to rational $n$. It is mainly the irrational $n$ for which we need Mean Value Theorem.